# How to clear the grid in Extjs

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a GridStore in Extjs which can store records with two grid columns. I have a problem when one record exists in Grid, if i delete the grid its been deleted successfully in server side, but that still exists in Grid.

Sample code:

```
    xtype: 'grid',
    store: 'SampleStore',
    border: false,
    width : 542,
    ref: '../sampleGrid',
    id: 'sampleGrid',
    columns: [
       {
       xtype: 'gridcolumn',
       dataIndex: 'name',
       header: 'Name',
       sortable: true,
   .............
    view: new Ext.grid.GridView({
    forceFit: true
    })
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use the forceFit option in the view. It's recommended to use flex on the grid itself. (not related to your issue but it's a suggestion)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you are using:

```
grid.getStore().remove(record); //remove record from grid
grid.getStore().sync(); //sync with server
```

If you want to remove all items, do:

```
grid.getStore().removeAll();
grid.getStore().sync();
```

But be careful! That will delete everything!

Comment: Don't forget to refresh the grid when store is cleared. If you don't do that, strange behaviour may happen.
grid.view.refresh()

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#yourGrid')[0].getStore().removeAll();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

var usrStore = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('LES.ossi.ossi-sampleapp.store.MainStore');

usrStore.removeAll();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).